# trying to duplicate the default process template in tfs 2013 and getting an error when trying to open it

Tags: tfs, build-process, alm, custom-build

I'm using the tfs and vs 2013.

I've downloaded the default build template (by pressing the "download" button in the build definition window), copied it, renames it, checked it in, and when I'm trying to set it as my build process template in the build definition a message box appears saying:
"Team Foundation Error"
"Valid Values are between 0 and 65535, inclusive.
Parameter name: codepage"

I want to keep my original default template (the tfs's default one) and work on a copy of it so I'll always have their basic one to get back to.

The default one's load alright and the build runs successfully with them but I need to make some custom one's for other builds...

Thanks a lot for any help! I've trying searching for it online and on the forum for a couple of days and couldn't find a trace :-\

Answer (score 0):

The default template is no more stored in Version Control, so it is impossible to overwrite it (and even than you can go back in history).

I suggest to compare the XAML between your copy and a freshly dowloaded copy of the default template, using a tool like WinDiff, Beyond Compare, WinMerge, Diff.Net or else.

Comment: My problem is that I can't change that build. if I use the one from the dropdown list it works but even if I just download it to my computer, put it in source control, check it in (because it can only load them from source control), load it back as a template- it gives me that message. If I try to open it in notepad it's gibrish...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know if restarting solved the problem but that's the only thing I can think of that changed from the last time I tried :)

Answer (score 0):

When you download the default TFS 2013 build template using the build definition editor in Visual Studio 2013, the file is returned in compressed in gzip format.

Rename the file and use a utility to extract the xaml.